# Sorting dates using SQL

Tags: sqlite

How can I sort by date here, while keeping all the parameters? 
I'm sorry, I'm really stupid in SQL.

```
SELECT 
  chat_identifier, 
  datetime(date/1000000000 + 978307200,'unixepoch','localtime'), 
  case when [error]=0 then 'ok' when [error]=1 then 'Not ok' end 
FROM 
  chat 
  INNER JOIN message 
    ON chat.ROWID = message.ROWID"
```

This query returns this:

```
[('Alex',), ('2020-02-16 05:22:49',), ('ok',)]
[('Grace',), ('2020-02-20 04:17:27',), ('ok',)]
[('Bob',), ('2020-02-16 05:22:25',), ('Not ok',)]
[('Brad',), ('2020-02-20 04:17:32',), ('ok',)]
[('Haruhi',), ('2020-02-16 05:22:10',), ('ok',)]
```

Comment: WIth an `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, to sort data, you use the `ORDER BY` clause followed by the colunns you wish to order by. By default, order by defaults to ascending order, but you can specifiy DESC after a column to indicate descending order.

For instance, given the following query:

```
SELECT chat_identifier, 
  datetime(date/1000000000 + 978307200,'unixepoch','localtime'), 
  case when [error]=0 then 'ok' when [error]=1 then 'Not ok' end 
FROM chat INNER JOIN message 
ON chat.ROWID = message.ROWID" 
ORDER BY chat_identifier
```

Should give something like this:

```
[('Alex',), ('2020-02-16 05:22:49',), ('ok',)]
[('Bob',), ('2020-02-16 05:22:25',), ('Not ok',)]
[('Brad',), ('2020-02-20 04:17:32',), ('ok',)]  
[('Grace',), ('2020-02-20 04:17:27',), ('ok',)]
[('Haruhi',), ('2020-02-16 05:22:10',), ('ok',)]
```

Since you are calculating the date field manually, you will also want to use a column alias. Thus, your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT chat_identifier, 
  datetime(date/1000000000 + 978307200,'unixepoch','localtime') AS my_date, 
  case when [error]=0 then 'ok' when [error]=1 then 'Not ok' end 
FROM chat INNER JOIN message 
ON chat.ROWID = message.ROWID" 
ORDER BY my_date
```